AWS Bedrock Agent Access Denied with Claude 3
I'm using AWS Bedrock with Pinecone as my vector database, and with Claude 2.1, it works smoothly. Still, when I try to update it (or create a new one) using the recently enabled Claude 3.0 Haiku or Sonnet, it triggers the following error:

There are no Advanced Prompts configurations or Action Groups; it's a simple use case of a PDF on an S3 bucket with Pinecone.
I'm running it using the "playground", the agent test environment of Bedrock, and I also have the Model enabled/subscribed.

When I look at the step trace, I see that the first two steps (pre-processing and orchestration) were successfully executed. However, the traces lack any meaningful information about the error, and I can only see that it found the expected results.

JIT: this is similar to this one Any one having access issues with claude-3-haiku or anthropic.claude-3-sonnet from boto client, but called differently.
It is not similar to this one: Amazon Bedrock Agent - Access denied when calling Bedrock. Check your request permissions and retry the request as The issue here was the lack of access to the model itself.
If I switch to Claude 2.1, it will work as expected.
I also tried to recreate the agent and the Knowledge Base unsuccessfully.
Additional information: The Knowledge Base testing environment works smoothly. The problem is when I link it to an Agent.
Knowledge Base Models I tried:

Titan Embeddings G1 - Textv1.2 - 1536 (with pinecone cosine 1536)
Embed Multilingualv3 - 1024 (with pinecone cosine 1024)

But I don't think the problem is related to the knowledge base because, as I mentioned before, the trace shows correct search results.
Has anyone faced this issue before or knows how to address it correctly?

Please check the policies of your Bedrock Agent's IAM role. If you want to be able to use all Claude models, try the one below. Make sure to change the region to your's.
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AmazonBedrockAgentBedrockFoundationModelPolicyProd",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "bedrock:InvokeModel",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:bedrock:us-east-1::foundation-model/anthropic.claude*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}


Thanks, Isc, you nailed it! This was precisely the issue. Well done.

I had another case, I used an existing model having the statement from this comment - access denied. I switched to "Create and use a new service role" and it worked
